# Google Apps Script bound script get container id

Tags: google-apps-script

If I publish a `doGet(e)` function from a GAS bound to a spreadsheet to create a web app, I can get a handle to the containing spreadsheet by using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

If I give my script all permissions to act as myself and give "everyone" permission to run it, after I close the spreadsheet, a call to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` returns `null`. I am forced to use `openById(Id)` or `openByUrl(Url)` with the correct parameter to get the handle.

I assumed there'd been a way to get the container's spreadsheet id from a bound script, otherwise if I wanted to copy a script from a spreadsheet to a new document, I'd have to update the url or the id in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"I assumed there'd been a way to get the container's spreadsheet id from a bound script, otherwise if I wanted to copy a script from a spreadsheet to a new document, I'd have to update the url or the id in the script."*

This is actually a bad assumption. When a standalone webapp is running there is no "active spreadsheet", the only way to access it is to open the spreadsheet by its ID or url.

This implies indeed that the script **has to be updated with the new ID** is you want to make it run along with a new sheet data set.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question, even if this is unfortunate: the fact that the script is bound to the spreadsheet should allow to call e.g. `getContainingSpreadsheet()`

Comment: Since you will in any case need to authorize the script before you deploy it you could write a script that gets the spreadsheet ID with the activeSpreadsheet.getId() method and stores the resulting ID in scriptProperties for later use. This way you wouldn't need to hard code it in the attached script.